# Does work between 2 bodies depend on their relative speed?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, energy, energy-conservation, work

Imagine a car standing on the road. Now the car starts to accelerate.

On the first part, the car accelerates from 0 m/s to 10 m/s.

Some of the fuel was used during this first part. let's call that amount X.

Now on the second part, the car accelerates from 10 m/s to 20 m/s.

Some of the fuel was used during this second part. let's call that amount Y.

Does Y > X ? if so, why ? Does work between 2 bodies depend on their relative speed ?

Neglect air resistance of course...

Answer (score 2):

> Does work between 2 bodies depend on their relative speed ?

It depends on what you mean.  Work is always force multiplied by distance.  Net work is also equal to the change in kinetic energy.  That's true here as well.  Note that the distance that the car traveled between starting and $v$ = 10 m/s is not the same as the distance between $v$ = 10 m/s and $v$ = 20 m/s.  The engine was pushing for longer during the second phase.  It took more energy to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Kinetic energy equals 1/2 of the product of the mass times the velocity squared, so the kinetic energy of the car going 20 m/s is 4 times the kinetic energy of the same car going 10 m/s. So if we discount frictions and air resistance and only focus on acceleration of the car, it will take 4 times the energy, not just double the energy, for a car to go from 0 to 20 m/s as it does to go from 0 to 10 m/s. So yes, Y > X.

Answer (score 0):

As other posters have said, $Y > X$ because the increase in kinetic energy going from 10 to 20 m/s is larger than the increase in going from 0 to 10 m/s.

To add on to this explanation, because I think it's a very good question - the answer may at first seem paradoxical. What if you saw the car accelerate from another frame of reference (say, another car on the road), in which all of the speeds were different? Then you would measure the car to have a completely different kinetic energy; but surely the amount of fuel burned would be the same?

It turns out that from a moving reference frame, you cannot neglect the motion of the *Earth*. As the first car accelerates from $v$ to $v+\Delta v$, it pushes back on the Earth, imparting on it a speed change of $\Delta v_\text{Earth} =  -\frac{m}{M_\text{Earth}} \Delta v$, consistent with the conservation of momentum.
Depending on the frame of reference you are using, this may either increase or decrease the observed kinetic energy of the Earth. This change turns out to be exactly right for observers in every reference frame to agree on the total kinetic energy change $\Delta E_\text{Earth} + \Delta E_\text{car}$ due to the acceleration.